# Powershell - Import-Excel without hidden rows

Tags: excel, powershell

How do I import an Excel .xlsx file into a Powershell without blank rows? I use Import-Excel to import a file. Just want to import non-hidden rows from the file.

I tried to filter with where-object, like in case blank rows and with out-gridview. Unfortunately, hidden values are imported every time.

```
    # Get all workbook sheets
    $sheets = Get-ExcelSheetInfo -Path $path
    # Get from all workbooks sheets data
    $Report = @()
    foreach($sheet in $sheets){
     if($sheet.Hidden -eq "Visible"){

     $Report += Import-Excel -Path $Path -WorksheetName $sheet.name | Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -ne '' } | Out-GridView -Title "Select rows to pass" -PassThru
           
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi , can your share a bit of your code please

Comment: Believe you forgot to post your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you have tried'

Comment: I just added sample code.

Comment: Each row in the sheet also has a `.Hidden` property (boolean) you can test on

Comment: But how I can access row from $sheet, after "." there is nothing like "row"